# Does the mounting of a Cisco 4948 switch need any more support than the standard mounting ears?

Tags: rackmount

For this application, we are building racks of equipment that will then be transported by truck to another location.  When a co-worker saw the 4948 in the rack mounted only by the ears, he questioned whether the mounting was robust enough for our transportation needs.

We actually have a number of switches to mount, and now I am wondering if mounting them only by the ears will survive transportation.  Has anyone ever had problems with mounting switches only by the ears?

I have seen some types of support brackets available.  Most of them seem to be for much heavier loads than just a switch.  I can't seem to find any lighter duty support brackets.  Does anyone have any recommendations?

Thanks,
Keith

Answer (score 1):

For transport you should be able to build a temporary support structure out of 2x4s (substitute your equivalent localized lumber designation) that provides support for the rear of the switch. Use suitable padding at the contact points. You don't say what else is on these racks above and below the switch. If there are other devices with existing support that you trust, then you may only need spacers. I would use some dense foam padding (such as from upholstery) that completely fills the vertical space (but not necessarily all the horizontal space).

If you're using a professional moving or delivery service, it ultimately depends on your contract with them (and whatever transportation laws govern such things where you are) as to what risks and losses they'll accept. If they're experienced with electronics, rely on them for guidance or even for the prep. Then the risk will be shifted onto them (except for the fact that you're paying for them to take that risk).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the 4948 is thin, so I'd be comfortable racking it with only the ears, but I don't think I'd be willing to transport it, in the rack, only secured by the ears. They can fail, and that's a lot of money down the tubes.

Answer (score 0):

If the racks are made of good quality steel and are being shipped on shock-pallets you should be fine but I wouldn't feel comfortable moving them on the unsupported bed of the truck.